# Extract words out of a text file

Tags: java, text

Let's say you have a text file like this one:
http://www.gutenberg.org/files/17921/17921-8.txt

Does anyone has a good algorithm, or open-source code, to extract words from a text file?
How to get all the words, while avoiding special characters, and keeping things like "it's", etc...

I'm working in Java.
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sounds like the right job for regular expressions. Here is some Java code to give you an idea, in case you don't know how to start:

```
String input = "Input text, with words, punctuation, etc. Well, it's rather short.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while ( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println(input.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
}
```

The pattern `[\w']+` matches all word characters, and the apostrophe, multiple times. The example string would be printed word-by-word. Have a look at the [Java Pattern class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to read more.

Comment: I had to slightly change the regexp to not include numbers, underscore, and to not have words that start with a quote, but otherwise, good!

Comment: I had to escape the \w like so: `Pattern.compile("[\\w']+");`

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but how would you exclude single quotes at the beginning or end of words?

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster You could use word boundaries for that. `Pattern.compile("\\b[\\w']+\\b");`

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\w[\\w-]+('\\w+)?")` will support hyphenated and even multiple-hyphenated words (`sous-vide`, `mise-en-scène`) as well as support an apostrophe, but not at the beginning of the word, and it must be followed by more word letters (`I've`, `sous-vide'n`). You may want to allow more letters after the apostrophe (i.e. to include plural possessives), in which case use `Pattern.compile("\\w[\\w-]+('\\w*)?")`.

Comment: it recognizes numbers as words how can i remove them? Not recognizing 'I'.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good approach to your problem:
This function receives your text as an input and returns an array of all the words inside the given text

```
private ArrayList<String> get_Words(String SInput){

    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder(SInput);
    ArrayList<String> all_Words_List = new ArrayList<String>();

    String SWord = "";
    for(int i=0; i<stringBuffer.length(); i++){
        Character charAt = stringBuffer.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(charAt) || Character.isDigit(charAt)){
            SWord = SWord + charAt;
        }
        else{
            if(!SWord.isEmpty()) all_Words_List.add(new String(SWord));
            SWord = "";
        }

    }

    return all_Words_List;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode would look like this:

```
create words, a list of words, by splitting the input by whitespace
for every word, strip out whitespace and punctuation on the left and the right
```

The python code would be something like this:

```
words = input.split()
words = [word.strip(PUNCTUATION) for word in words]
```

where

```
PUNCTUATION = ",. \n\t\\\"'][#*:"
```

or any other characters you want to remove.

I believe Java has equivalent functions in the String class: [String](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).split() .

---

Output of running this code on the text you provided in your link:

```
>>> print words[:100]
['Project', "Gutenberg's", 'Manual', 'of', 'Surgery', 'by', 'Alexis', 
'Thomson', 'and', 'Alexander', 'Miles', 'This', 'eBook', 'is', 'for', 
'the', 'use', 'of', 'anyone', 'anywhere', 'at', 'no', 'cost', 'and', 
'with', 'almost', 'no', 'restrictions', 'whatsoever', 'You', 'may', 
'copy', 'it', 'give', 'it', 'away', 'or', 're-use', 'it', 'under', 
... etc etc.
```

Comment: The advantage of this code over regular expressions is that it can be done simply in a single pass.

Comment: Yes Java has a 'split' method, but it doesn't have the equivalent of the 'strip' method.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to match

([A-Za-z])+('([A-Za-z])*)?

right?

Answer (score 0):

You could try regex, using a pattern you've made, and run a count the number of times that pattern has been found.