# What is the java regex to extract words and abbreviations?

Tags: java, regex

Consider this sentence: I studied at U.C.L.A in U.S.A.. One of my professors' kid was my best friend.

Using the regex `[\\w']+` suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276546/extract-words-out-of-a-text-file), I can extract the words. But, the abbreviated words are coming as separate words for each characters. So, U.S.A. is getting extracted as  three words as U, S, and A. I want to extract the abbreviated words like U.C.L.A. and U.S.A. also as one word.

Please suggest the regex.

Adding one additional requirement:
The words like "FBs", "GTs" etc. should be considered as one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this pattern
`((?:[A-Z]\.)+[A-Z]?|[a-zA-Z']+)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/26)

Comment: ***STACK OVERFLOW IS NOT A CODING SERVICE***.