# Java- store odd and even words from text file into two separate array lists

Tags: java, arrays

So far i just have this outputting the whole text file. I need the program to store even(words with even number of letters) and odd(words with odd number of letters) into the respective arrays i have created thus far... e.g: 3 letter word such as "and" should be stored into oddList[] array. And a word like "life" stored into evenList[]. I also need to make sure that if a word like "and" occurs three times in the text file, i need to store it ONCE in the oddList[].

Right now, this prints each word in the text file line by line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: If you understand what you need to do exactly, then please share the steps you have in mind, and specify the steps you don't know how to do (after researching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm is often referred to as a partition. In a partition, elements are categorized into 2 groups based on whether or not they meet some condition (called a predicate). In this case your condition is whether the string has an even length or not.

In Java 8, this algorithm is available to you out-of-the-box with [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-). You may want to begin your research by looking for answers in terms of "partitioning" the words into 2 sets. You can get the words from the file by using this answer: [Extract words out of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/276546/5743988). From there, just partition the words into two `Set`s.

This sounds like a homework assignment, so using advanced Java 8 features may not be available to you, but just to be educational, here is how it would be structured:

```
Predicate<String> hasEvenLength = (String word) -> word.length() % 2 == 0;

Map<Boolean,Set<String>> partition =
    Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))                       // get the lines
         .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\W+")::splitAsStream)  // split the lines into words
         .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(hasEvenLength, // parition by even length
             Collectors.mapping(String::toUpperCase,       // uppercase
                 Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)))); // put into sorted set

Set<String> evenWords = partition.get(Boolean.TRUE);
Set<String> oddWords = partition.get(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129883/discussion-on-answer-by-4castle-java-store-odd-and-even-words-from-text-file-in).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: break the problem into smaller ones.  For example:

1. How to split a line into words.  (I'm guessing that there is more than one word per line of your sonnet.)
2. How to find the number of characters in a word.
3. How to decide if a number is odd or even.  (Hint - that is *junior school arithmetic* ...)
4. How to put something into a list.

**Hint**: `String evenList[];` is not declaring an "array list".  It is declaring an "array of String", and it is NOT initialising it.

In this case, you *should* be using an array list.  Specifically an instance of `ArrayList<String>`.

**UPDATE** - Correction.  Since you want duplicate elimination in the word "lists", use a set rather than a list.  I would suggest either `TreeSet<String>` or `LinkedHashSet<String>`.  Read the javadocs to understand the difference.

**Hint**: Most of the followup questions arising out of my hints above can (and should!) be answered by reading the javadocs of the classes that have been mentioned.

Comment: Since they don't want any duplicates in the lists, they may actually want a `HashSet<String>`